# Did Terry Pratchett ever explain the inspiration behind the Luggage?

Tags: discworld

The Luggage is one of the iconic *Discworld* characters, but did Terry Pratchett ever explain where the inspiration came from for the sociopathic walking trunk with internals that seem to act like the TARDIS (a box that is much much bigger on the inside, from *Doctor Who*)?

Comment: Probably his own crazy, brilliant mind.

Comment: You do know most wheely suitcases are sociopathic right?

Comment: I always assumed it was a pun based on the fact that Twoflower was a tourist and the Luggage was his _travelling_ luggage (as opposed to an overnight bag).

Answer (score 128, accepted):

In the Dedication of [*Sourcery*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1497), Terry Pratchett writes:

> DEDICATION

> Many years ago I saw, in Bath, a very large American lady towing a huge tartan suitcase very fast on little rattly wheels which caught in the pavement cracks and generally gave it a life of its own. At that moment the Luggage was born. Many thanks to that lady and everyone else in places like Power Cable, Neb., who don't get nearly enough encouragement.

Comment: For those not familiar with the reference to Power Cable, Nebraska, please see the section on *Mort* in https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/TV_and_film_adaptations ; also see https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Power_Cable

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the traits of the luggage (that is, its interior space, sapience, etc) were all tropes from other places, even if not specifically mentioned. For example, it is made of wood is from the sapient pear tree (there's a pun there, in case you missed it; *sap*-ient). The bigger-on-the-inside as a trope has been around for a long, long time showing up in Heinlein, Narnia, Doctor Who, Myth Adventures (which predates Discworld, if only just), to name a few. There is nothing new under the sun, but fresh combinations abound.

Comment: He also mentioned in the art of the discworld that it  was based on something he used use in his DND games, a chest with thousands of little legs for carrying loot that blindly followed orders, often getting lost when given careless orders. so there was TWO inspirations. https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/The_Luggage